# Why 3 mmm and 4mmmm point group symmetry elements do not exist?

Tags: solid-state-physics, group-theory, x-ray-crystallography

Why 3 mmm and 4mmmm point group symmetry elements do not exist? How we can say 3 mmm and 4mmmm are rather equivalent to 3m and 4mm respectively?